# Manage a space where you can move things (Silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, pan

I'm thinking at the better way to manage a "workspace" in my application, where the user could move things in this space, and could pan for instance.

Let's imagine I have my application interface, with some buttons all around, a treeview etc. and in the middle, a Canvas with some widgets the user can move and work with, and he could pan this space to move in it.

For the pan, I was thinking to handle the MouseLeftButtonDown in this space (that switch a boolean "UserMoving" to true), and on the MouseMove, to apply on translation to the space (from the Delta between the 2 events), until I detect a MouseLeftButtonUp, to know he has stopped (UserMoving to false). The problem is that if the user "mouse left button up" not on the space itself (a Canvas), I will never know he has released the mouse. What's the best to manage the fact that he can release the pan (or the drag&drop of a widget) wherever in the application?

Do anybody has already manage something like that and can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call the [UIElement.CaptureMouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse%28VS.95%29.aspx) on your Canvas at the mouse down.  This will keep the canvas receiving mouse events, even if the user moves outside of it's region.

On mouse up, call [ReleaseMouseCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.releasemousecapture%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).